# Android animation blinking xml shape for checkbox

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml

I wanted to make my checkbox animate by making it blink from color 1 to color 2 by using only XML. Well what I have is an oval shape colored gradient red when unchecked and I want it to blink into a blinking green when the checkbox is checked. What do I need to achieve this?

Comment: By blinking do you mean change color more than once? What have you tried?

Comment: Not exactly. Any trick can do such as changing the alpha. I tried it once using the interpolator as seen in one question here with repetition but nothing happens and it just turns all black. Sorry I can't find the code anymore.

Comment: try this link....https://gist.github.com/cesco89/9144189